# Determine pattern for 4 given equations

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

We are given this information and the puzzle is to find the pattern of how these given statements can all be true.

$1+~~4=~~~~5$
$2+~~5=~~12$
$3+~~6=~~21$
$8+11=201$

Good luck!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each answer moves

> one numerical base downwards.

So

> 1 + 4 = 5  (5 in decimal = 5 in base 6)
>  2 + 5 = 12  (7 in decimal = 12 in base 5)
>  3 + 6 = 21  (9 in decimal = 21 in base 4)
>  8 + 11 = 201  (19 in decimal = 201 in base 3)

Comment: Wow very impressive and absolutely correct.  That is the answer I was looking for and u got it in record time (so quickly I could not even accept your answer so soon as it would not allow me to).  I think the low numbered digits ($0,1,2$) was somewhat of a giveaway though.

Answer (score -4):

The first number is

> (1 , 2, 3, ....Etc) + Second number (1,2,3,4 .. Etc) = (First number+ First number * second number).

Or for better understanding:

> X + Y = (X+XY)

Comment: 8+11 would produce 96 according to this rule

Comment: It is funny that someone would post a wrong answer after I already previously accepted the correct answer and commented that it was absolutely correct.